# Error Running VBScript from NotePad

Tags: vbscript

I am new to vbscript and running procedures.  I found some code that I'm trying to test so that I can get a feel for how vbscript works, and I am not sure why I am receiving an error message.  I have created the below code in NotePad and then saved the file as a .vbs file on my desktop.  Here is the code:

```
i=10

If i=10 Then

msgbox("This is my first script, Click OK to close")

Else

msgbox(“Hello world”)

End if
```

I thought that I would be able to open the file and get the message.  Instead I am receiving the following error message:

> Windows Script Host
>
> Script: (my file location on my desktop) Line: 9 Char: 8 Error:
>
> Invalid character Code: 800A0408 Source: Microsoft VBScript
> compilation error

Answer (score 2):

Replace

`msgbox(“Hello world”)`

with

`msgbox("Hello world")`

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much for the quick response!

Comment: No worries ... always make sure that the vbscript code is in ANSI format.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like line 9 character 8 is a “ and not a " character. That is probably the issue. You would also need to replace the ” character after world with a " character.